# Unresponsive .NET Kestrel on Ubuntu 20

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, razor-pages, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to run .NET on Ubuntu, with the following appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=1.2.3.5:1234;Database=somedomain.com;Uid=default;Pwd=password;"
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:7000",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/cert.pem",
          "KeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/privkey.pem"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

It starts up fine, but if I open port 7000 then even `telnet` can't make a connection to Kestrel. However, running `lsof -i:7000` shows it listening on that port. What gives?

**Update:**

Running telnet from outside doesn't work, but from localhost it's OK.
If Nginx is running and I try to connect to port 443 in a browser, it returns '403 Forbidden'. Here's the Nginx config for the site:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
server_tokens  off;

upstream somedomain.com
{
    server 127.0.0.1:7000;
}

server
{
    root /var/www/somedomain.com;
    server_name somedomain.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/somedomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include                   /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam               /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    #Redirects all traffic
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass https://somedomain.com;
        limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server
{
    if ($host = somedomain.com)
    {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name somedomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Update 2:**

I updated the NGINX configuration with the following, but the issue persists:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:7000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the firewall on your Ubuntu server is not blocking incoming connections on port 7000? also check for port binding... it's possible that another process is already bound to port 7000

Comment: Thanks @YoushaAleayoub, yes I opened the firewall before testing with telnet. But in any case, NGINX should be connecting to Kestrel locally. Nothing was bound to 7000 beforehand..

Comment: Even worse, if the load balancer hits the server instead of going directly, the message is '502 Bad Gateway'.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed the issue described by binding to `*` instead of `localhost`:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:7000"
      }
    }
  }
```

There's still errors now, but exceptions from my code in the project rather than simply not responding to requests. So I'll consider this case closed.